# Use PHP to write parser and then save to local with Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap for Android

Tags: php, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Assuming that I have a php parser that can parse the news page into JSON format
Then, for my android apps, When I open the apps and click "news" icon, I would like to send request using the php parser and get result in JSON format.
After that, I want to save the news into local so that users can read the news faster.
Is it possible to save them in local?
If yes, after it save to local, how to display it in the list dynamically?
Then, after clicking one item of the list, it should display the detail news, but I should write I template page that insert the news selected dynamically or write many .html??
Finally, what kind of methods can be save to local? SQL??
I have researched a lot in web, but I still confused with JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap API, Please give suggestion

Comment: -1 too many questions. questions too broad. someone must write a book to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to receive the news every time you start the app you can just save them into a javascript array until your app is closed.

For collapsible nice display have a look at the [jQuery Mobile Doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/content/content-collapsible.html)

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3>I'm a header</h3>
<p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm open and displayed on the page, but you can click the header to hide me.</p>
</div>
```

You can also write yourself a nice method browsing through your JSON object and append the `<h3>title</h3><p>content</p>` structure to your div.

If you do so make sure to call   `$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();` after your loop to make everything collapsible again. (jQuery is a little bit lazy there ^.- )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting without PhoneGap, but rather just build your webpage with HTML, JS and JqueryMobile. I don't see anything limiting you from implementing PhoneGap at a later stage (you could in the meantime save the local data in the local HTML5 localStorage/sessionStorage/SQL).

Once you got all of that working, you could migrate to PhoneGap (which really is just a native wrapper around your html code).

Comment: Thx Leon, my main concern is that Jquery mobile suport local storage? Can you give me some idea??

Comment: localStorage/sessionStorage is a key/value storage and it's a feature of HTML5 and nothing related to PhoneGap! You could even use the [jStore JQuery plugin](http://www.jstorage.info/) which adds additional features - personally I've always used it directly, i.e. `localStorage.mykey="myvalue"`